# Multiple match and replace

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string:

```
<x>&nbsp;<span class='var'>or<tg>test<pk>testing</pk></tg><tx>or</tx><tg>teste<pk>testando</pk></tg></span></x>
```

I'm using this pattern:

```
<tg>(.*)<pk>(.*)</pk></tg>
```

But it's replacing from the first `<tg>` to the last one, ignoring the `</tg>` in the middle.

My replacement string:

```
<a href='def.aspx?&word=$2'>$1</a>
```

Comment: Have a look at this [famous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)

Comment: I'm not really asking about parsing html....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*` is [*greedy*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) so it's continuing even after finding matches. You can tweak your regular expression slightly to change this behavior:

```
<tg>([^<]*)<pk>([^<]*)</pk></tg>
```

(that is, allow anything except for an opening `<` inside of `<tg>` and `<pk>` tags using a negated character class)

or:

```
<tg>(.*?)<pk>(.*?)</pk></tg>
```

(use the [lazy quantifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `*` to make the engine match as few occurrences as possible)

Comment: Thank you. Ended up using your second suggestion